# TypeError: "function()" takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given al pasar argumento a Timer()

Tags: python, hilos, timer

Estoy creando una función que se ejecute cada n segundos. Para ello, he creado una clase que ejecuta indefinidamente Timer() hasta que en algún lugar del código se para la ejecución manualmente mediante Timer.cancel(). También necesito pasarle al Timer como argumento una clase que será necesaria para la ejecución del hilo. Las clases que intervienen son las siguientes:

```
#call_class.py

from threading import Timer

class Monitoring_Timer():

    def __init__(self, time, function, obj):
        self.time = time
        self.function = function
        self.obj = obj
        self.thread = Timer(self.time, self.exec_function, args=(self.obj,))

    def exec_function(self, o):
        self.function(o)
        self.thread = Timer(self.time, self.exec_function, args=(self.obj,))
        self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self.thread.cancel()


class Lista_prueba(object):

    __slots__ = ("calls_list")
```

La creación de las clases y sus llamadas serían así:

```
from call_class import Monitoring_Timer, Lista_prueba

def printer(c):
   c.calls_list.append("hola")

c = Lista_prueba()
c.calls_list = []

t = Monitoring_Timer(2.0, printer, c)
t.start()
```

Pues bien, cuando ejecuto el programa, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1254, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: exec_function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[]
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme a qué se debe y cómo solucionarlo? Ya que creo que estoy pasando los argumentos de forma correcta a los hilos.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: No obtengo el error que describes. Pero la función `exec_function` creará un hilo nuevo a cada vez que se la llame. Como se llama a sí misma creará infinitos hilos. Aunque llames a cancel, sólo cancelarás el último de ellos.